# New to asynchronous programming in JavaScript. Any advice?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, browser, asynchronous

Asynchronous callbacks are great but when one callback depends on the result of another I have callbacks with api calls that have callbacks, and so on.

```
apiCall(function () { apiCall(function () { apiCall(function () ...
```

I can name the callback functions instead of including them inline. That looks prettier and has less nesting but I do not find it any easier to read.

Here is an example. I need to query the local sqlite database, use the result to query a server, then use the response to update the local database.

```
function sync() {
  db.transaction(
function (transaction) {
  execute(transaction, 'SELECT max(server_time) AS server_time FROM syncs;', [],
      function (transaction, results) { // Query results callback
        var t = results.rows.item(0).server_time;
        $.post('sync.json', { last_sync_time: (t || '1980-01-01') },
           function (data) { // Ajax callback
             db.transaction(
               function(transaction) {
                 $(data.thing).each(function () {
                              var thing = new Thing(this.thing);
                              thing.insert(transaction);
                            });
               });
           });
      });
});
}
```

Is there a way to untagle this (other than naming the callbacks)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're too quick to discard un-nesting things by naming your functions rather than writing them inline. This is pretty much the only way to clean up that mess.

Instead of:

```
do_a(
  function () {
    // more nesting...
  }
);
```

Use names to provide a bit of clarity and purpose to each function:

```
function on_a_complete() {

}

do_a(on_a_complete);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question. Naming your callbacks is really the only way to clean this up anymore.  Something like:

```
execute(transaction, 'SELECT max(server_time) AS server_time FROM syncs;', [],handleLocalResults, errorHandler);

handleLocalResults = function (transaction, results)...

handleServerResults = func...
```

Answer (score 0):

Naming the callbacks is one thing you can do, but the other thing that you need to do is to have non-overlapping SQL transactions.  ([1](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/))

Your first transaction should be like this:

```
// The whole thing starts here
db.transaction(selectTimeCB, null, ajaxPost);
```

The transaction starts with the callback to select the time, and when the *transaction* is complete, make a call to the ajaxPost operation.

```
// Initial transaction to get server_time
var selectTimeCB = function(t) {
  var query = 'SELECT max(server_time) AS server_time FROM syncs';
  t.executeSql(query, [], postLastSyncCB);
};

// This saves the results from the above select, and nothing else.
var server_time;
var postLastSyncCB = function(t, results) {
  server_time = results.rows.item(0).server_time;
};

var ajaxPost = function() {
  $.post('sync.json', { last_sync_time: (server_time || '1980-01-01') }, nextDbTransaction);
};
```

If you have overlapped SQL transactions, that can really kill the performance of the database.  I recently did a test of 200 mixed transactions on a database with a bit over 500 rows, and found that keeping the transactions separate reduced a run time of over 90 seconds to 3-5 seconds.